# Ubuntu 16.04 on macbook pro 11,2 - nvidia card not recognized at all

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, macbook

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on this Macbook, which has two graphic cards: Intel and Nvidia.

When I go to the restricted driver section I cannot see any Nvidia card.

with the command `lspci -vnn | grep VGA`

I get only this output

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0d26] (rev 08) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

and with `sudo lshw -numeric -C display` I get

I get

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:D26]
   vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 08
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:35 memory:a0000000-a03fffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:1000(size=64)
```

I searched around, but found no solutions.

How can I get the Nvidia card recognized?

Thank you

Comment: Have you installed `nvidia-prime`?  `sudo apt install nvidia-prime`

Comment: Yes, already did. And when I call `sudo prime-select nvidia` it actually seems to select the Nvidia card. But `lspci` give the same message, only the Intel card is recognized. Also `nvidia-detector` gives 'none' as reply

Comment: Did you eventually find the solution or workaround? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Yes, actually I find that I have one of the few models which actually does NOT have the NVidia card.

Answer (score -1):

The card is being recognized, since it is showing up in those commands. Try this page for installing nvidia drivers, I have had success with it.

[Install Nvidia Drivers In Linux](http://www.tecmint.com/install-nvidia-drivers-in-linux)

Comment: Only the Intel card is recognized, not the Nvidia one. That's my problem...

Comment: Ah, Ok. Are you able to re seat it at all? Can you see any lights on/blinking/anything on it? You could check /var/log/boot and /var/log/dmesg to see if it was detected somewhere in there, that would mean was recognized. You could also look up udev and do some testing with that to see if it recognizes your card and what device node is created in /dev. My favorite is 'udevadm monitor' to see if usb devices are detected when plugged in. If you had a way to enable/disable the video card then this command may help. You may have to check udev logs or modify the command to check for the card. HTH!

Comment: Nothing interesting in /var/log/boot.log, and nothing in dmseg... it's like it is completely absent. And I have no bios where enter